# Can't access my apache server from outside LAN (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I know this question was asked a lot, but unfortunately none of the posts really helped..

I'm trying to set up an Apache server on my Raspberry Pi.
I managed to set it up correctly I think, but I can't access it from outside my LAN.
I thought maybe it's my ISP blocking 80 port, so changed the port to 3000, still no luck.
It seems like there's no problem with the apache configuration:

```
pi@raspberrypi /home/pi $ netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

When I'm trying to access it from inside of my LAN with this address: http://109.65.74.55:3000/index.html it works fine, But when trying the same address from outside of my LAN - no connection.

ipconfig on my PC gives me the following:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection: 
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b57c:a8cd:7d5:a935%10 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.6 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138.
```

I guess that means I'm behind NAT?

Comment: What is your LAN network? Are you behind NAT?

Comment: ipconfig on my PC gives me the following: Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b57c:a8cd:7d5:a935%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.138.             I guess that means I'm behind NAT?

Comment: Please *edit* this info into your question. As you see, in a comment it's illegible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot work. The outside LAN does not know how to handle the IP of your RaspberryPi.  (=how to route the packets to reach your RaspberryPi)

go to http://www.whatismyip.com/ to find out your public IP. Note it down, but don't tell us.

You will have to point to this IP if you want to reach your RaspberryPi.
Which port to use you have to define in a port forward in your router.

Power off and on your router and revisit the above url.

If your IP changed, then you have a dynamic IP and need a DynDNS service to get a always valid URL to reach your local network from outside.

Could you please do a `nmap 10.0.0.*` and `nmap 109.65.74.*` to find out the IP addresses in your local network?
It is strange that your router is 10.0.0.138 but the RaspberryPi is 109.65.74.55

If you are behind a NAT no one can attack your network using this information.

PS. Why the hell did they move this question from serverfault to unix?!

Comment: The post was moved here by serverfault - EEAA and sven - as they thought it was off-topic for their site.  Serverfault is _a question and answer site for managing information technology systems in a business environment_. While the Raspberry Pi _could_ be used in a business environment, it most probably isn't ;-)